# How to obtain Principle value within Policy Generator?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-policies

For creating a new bucket policy within my Policy Generator, do I need to create a IAM user to obtain the Principle value from or is there another way to get this Principle value?

Comment: Yep went fine, just used the number for my region at the bottom of this page "https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-access-logs.html#access-logging-bucket-permissions" which works fine.

Comment: So how would I specifically be able to see the logs within the file, do I just press 'Open' within the ELBAccessLogTestFile once running Instances and it will display the load being transferred?

Comment: I don't remember if they are compressed or not. But if they are in plain text, then you can just open them in the browser, or download and then process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Principal](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_principal.html#Principal_specifying) can be your IAM user/role or AWS Account number. So you don't have to create any of them, just use existing ones.